# iOS Facebook SDK Not Redirecting After Authentication on Device

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I recently followed a tutorial (http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) which outlines how to use the Facebook iOS SDK in Swift to create a login view.

Everything works fine when I test in the iOS Simulator, but when I load my application (and the sample app provided by the tutorial author) on an actual iOS device, the application attempts to open the Facebook app installed on my device and leaves me with a blank screen with a cancel button in the top left corner.

I know that this at least partially works on a device as if I remove my bundle identifier from the Facebook developer page, I get an error that states I must add it back in.

I get the feeling I'm missing some sort of redirect that's necessary to hand off the authorization process from the Facebook app back to my app, but any advice anyone has would be awesome.

Also, I'm running XCode 6.4 targeting iOS 8.3, but I'm testing on a device running iOS 9. Everything seems to be running fine, but maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: Can you post your code please? May have an idea of what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The clue on your question is iOS 9, I highly recommend checking out this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 you're most likely missing many important steps as well as the latest Facebook iOS SDK.

Comment: Check the documentation is not a good answer unless the documentation has a clear solution.